# Angular ui-grid 100% height inside ng-view

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

Using Angular, Bootstrap, and UI-Grid in an attempt to create a page with a navbar header and an `<ng-view>` container with a 100% height ui-grid table.  You can see a demo here of what I've got so far.  You'll note that the nav bar pushes the table footer right off the page.

http://embed.plnkr.co/qxPMevXLJAOfvGk0iVBH/

The closest I've gotten is http://brianhann.com/make-ui-grid-take-up-the-whole-page/ but I've read quite a few other posts to not success.  I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated.  CSS always seems to get the better of me.

Comment: is the height of your navbar header static? if yes, try height: calc(98vh - 100px); for the grid, where 100px will be the height of your navbar header.

Comment: Yes, my navbar height was static.  That seems to have done it.  It works like I've wanted.  Thank you very much.  If you'll post as an answer, I'll flag as correct to get you some points.

Comment: Cheers, just moved it to answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the height of your navbar header is static, try

```
height: calc(98vh - 100px);
```

for the grid, where 100px will be the height of your navbar header